# Panorama Image doesn't move with title

Tags: image, xaml, panorama-control

I've added an Image to the Panorama title in an app.

XAML:

```
<phone:Panorama Title="MSFT Insider" Background="#FFD8D8D8" Foreground="Black" Style="{StaticResource PanoramaStyle1}">
```

PanoramaStyle1:

```
<phone:PhoneApplicationPage.Resources>
        <Style x:Key="PanoramaStyle1" TargetType="phone:Panorama">
            <Setter Property="ItemsPanel">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                        <Primitives:PanoramaPanel x:Name="panel"/>
                    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{StaticResource PhoneForegroundBrush}"/>
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="phone:Panorama">
                        <Grid>
                            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
                                <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <Primitives:PanningBackgroundLayer x:Name="BackgroundLayer" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Grid.RowSpan="2">
                                <Border x:Name="background" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"/>
                            </Primitives:PanningBackgroundLayer>
                            <StackPanel HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Orientation="Horizontal">
                                <Image Height="100" Source="Assets/Logos/Logo_transparente.png" Stretch="Fill" Margin="20,0,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                                <Primitives:PanningTitleLayer x:Name="TitleLayer" CharacterSpacing="-35" ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding TitleTemplate}" Content="{TemplateBinding Title}" FontSize="80" FontFamily="{StaticResource PhoneFontFamilyLight}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="128" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="10,0,0,0"/>
                            </StackPanel>
                            <Primitives:PanningLayer x:Name="ItemsLayer" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Grid.Row="1">
                                <ItemsPresenter x:Name="items"/>
                            </Primitives:PanningLayer>
                        </Grid>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
```

The problem is that the image does not move with the text when i slide left or right.

This is what i mean:

[image: Panorama image doesn't move]

What I can do to make it move? I have found anything searching.

Comment: Don't the image must be of at least a certain width ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of putting **PanningTitleLayer** in StackPanel together with your image like :

```
<StackPanel HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Orientation="Horizontal">
     <Image Height="100" Source="Assets/Logos/Logo_transparente.png" Stretch="Fill" Margin="20,0,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
     <Primitives:PanningTitleLayer x:Name="TitleLayer" CharacterSpacing="-35" ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding TitleTemplate}" Content="{TemplateBinding Title}" FontSize="80" FontFamily="{StaticResource PhoneFontFamilyLight}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="128" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="10,0,0,0"/>
</StackPanel>
```

You should try putting your image in StackPanel together with  **TextBlock** in PanningTitleLayer's **ContentPresenter** like this :

```
<Primitives:PanningTitleLayer x:Name="TitleLayer" CharacterSpacing="-35" ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding TitleTemplate}"  FontSize="80" FontFamily="{StaticResource PhoneFontFamilyLight}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="128" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="10,0,0,0">
    <ContentPresenter>
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
            <Image Height="100" Source="Assets/Logos/Logo_transparente.png" Stretch="Fill" Margin="20,0,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
            <TextBlock Text="{TemplateBinding Title}"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </ContentPresenter>
</Primitives:PanningTitleLayer>
```

Note that `<Primitives:PanningTitleLayer>` does not have `Content` attribute defined anymore. Instead it have `<ContentPresenter></ContentPresenter>`, and that **TextBlock** is now bounded to Title (`<TextBlock Text="{TemplateBinding Title}"/>`)

I hope this helps ...

Comment: Great help for a XAML noob ;-)